# Sorting with priority in jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

```js
var data = [{
  "type": "local",
  "name": "Frank",
  "age": 89
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "Mary",
  "age": 76
}, {
  "type": "local",
  "name": "John",
  "age": 36
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "James",
  "age": 10
}, {
  "type": "local",
  "name": "Lily",
  "age": 17
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "Harry",
  "age": 67
}, {
  "type": "local",
  "name": "Larry",
  "age": 7
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "Harold",
  "age": 37
}]

var sort_by = function(field, reverse, primer) {

  var key = primer ?
    function(x) {
      return primer(x[field])
    } :
    function(x) {
      return x[field]
    };

  reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;

  return function(a, b) {
    return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
  }
}


data = data.sort(sort_by('age', true, parseFloat));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

This is my how I sort my data. Currently what it does is sort the age from oldest to youngest. It is doing fine as it is. I found this sorting in some post in SO.

I want to add another requirement on the process. I want to first be able to find all with type local sort it from oldest to youngest **meaning all local first from oldest to youngest** then after sorting all the local.. Sort the rest from oldest to youngest still.

`UPDATE`:

There will is another type but it doesnt matter here because All I need is to first make all the local at first in the list but still in oldest to youngest and then the rest is still in oldest to youngest.

Comment: Use `filter()` before calling `sort()`: `data.filter(d => d.type == 'local').sort(...`

Comment: how do you like to change the sort order to ascending, should the locals comes ther first, too?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when i used filter it removed the other types i dont want that i only want to make local in first of list in oldest to youngest then the rest will be oldest to youngest

Comment: @Giant ah, ok. I misunderstood your requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to check if `type` is equal to `'local'`, then the item has to be moved up. This is done by a check and a delta of the comparison.

For example

> ```
>                                  cb-ca
>     a      b  check a  check b  result  comment
> -----  -----  -------  -------  ------  ------------------
> local  local     true     true       0  take b.age - a.age
> local  other     true    false      -1  move a to top
> other  local    false     true       1  move a to bottom
> other  other    false    false       0  take b.age - a.age
> ```

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.type === 'local') - (a.type === 'local') || b.age - a.age;
});
```

```js
var data = [{ type: "local", name: "Frank", age: 89 }, { type: "visitor", name: "Mary", age: 76 }, { type: "local", name: "John", age: 36 }, { type: "visitor", name: "James", age: 10 }, { type: "local", name: "Lily", age: 17 }, { type: "visitor", name: "Harry", age: 67 }, { type: "local", name: "Larry", age: 7 }, { type: "visitor", name: "Harold", age: 37 }],
    sort_by = function(field, reverse, primer) {
        var key = primer ?
                function(x) { return primer(x[field]); } :
                function(x) { return x[field]; };

        reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;

        return function(a, b) {
            return (b.type === 'local') - (a.type === 'local') || reverse * (key(a) - key(b));
        };
    };

data.sort(sort_by('age', true, parseFloat));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what i want is all local to go first but in oldest to youngest and then rest should still be oldest to youngest there is another type aside from local and visitor but it doesnt matter as long as all local first in oldest to youngest then the rest oldest to youngest

Comment: can you add a bit explanation so that i can understand what it did since you change the code totally.. that would be helpful to me and other reader

Comment: can you please add explanation i still dont understand but i will tick it as answer

Comment: @Giant, does it help? you can chaind sort criteria by using logical OR, which evalueates until a truthy value is found.

Comment: i sort of wanted to know which part does the sorting of locals and which part does the sorting of age i mean the `var key = primer ?
                function(x) { return primer(x[field]); } :
                function(x) { return x[field]; };

        reverse = !reverse ? 1 : -1;` i dont understand what it does

Comment: it's a part of your code. it basically changes the sort order from descending to ascending.

Answer (score 0):

I know it looks kind of dumb, but it works ok for me...

https://jsfiddle.net/wuhduhren/vcyvwq4k/5/

```
function sort(data){
  var personNotLocal = [];
  var sortedData = [];
  var sortedCleanData = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var personalData = data[i];
    if (personalData["type"] == 'local'){
      sortedData.push([personalData['age'], personalData]);
      sortedData.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] - b[1]}); //sort by age
    } else {
      personNotLocal.push([personalData['age'], personalData]);
      personNotLocal.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] - b[1]}); //sort by age
    }
  }
  sortedData.push.apply(sortedData, personNotLocal); //append personNotLocal array after sortedData

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedData.length; i++) {
    sortedCleanData.push(sortedData[i][1]);
  }
  return sortedCleanData;
}

var data = [{
  "type": "local",
  "name": "Frank",
  "age": 89
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "Mary",
  "age": 76
}, {
  "type": "local",
  "name": "John",
  "age": 36
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "James",
  "age": 10
}, {
  "type": "local",
  "name": "Lily",
  "age": 17
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "Harry",
  "age": 67
}, {
  "type": "local",
  "name": "Larry",
  "age": 7
}, {
  "type": "visitor",
  "name": "Harold",
  "age": 37
}];


console.log(JSON.stringify(sort(data), null, 2));
```